# Какой признак сходимости применяется для данного ряда?

Tags: математика

Добрый день. Какой признак сходимости применяется для **[этого](http://s019.radikal.ru/i600/1205/2a/6d01f13af07c.jpg)** ряда?

*По-моему Интегральный признак Коши*

Прав?

Comment: Насчёт использования признака Даламбера, я, пожалуй, был не прав: по нему получается, что ряд сходится, а по интегральному признаку расходится (логарифм, хоть и от логарифма, но, всё же, растёт).

Comment: @Александр Моисеенко, Это вопрос на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что Вы правы, можно применять интегральный признак Коши, но, лучше спросите математиков (здесь на другом форуме). По интегральному признаку Коши получается натуральный логарифм от натурального логарифма. Если сомневаетесь, то попробуйте применить признак Даламбера.

Comment: Спасибо большое, DelphiM0ZG. Вопросик теперь закрывать можно. Щас следующий вопросик оформлю.